# "AssertDescription: CDK bootstrap stack version 6 required"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm fairly new (today its the first day) with Amazon CDK. I have been currently following the [initial tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/hello_world.html) in Amazon's CDK page.

I have installed `aws` and `cdk`:

```sh
aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.5 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.11.0-43-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off

cdk --version
2.3.0 (build beaa5b2)
```

I have added the following code to create a simple lambda function:

*notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/bin/notify_todo_schedule_full_day.ts*

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack } from '../lib/notify_todo_schedule_full_day-stack';

const app = new cdk.App();
new NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack(app, 'NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack', {});
```

*notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/lib/notify_todo_schedule_full_day-stack.ts*

```js
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { aws_lambda_nodejs as lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

export class NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    new lambda.NodejsFunction(this, "notifyTodoScheduleFullDay", {
      entry: "src/index.ts",
      handler: "handler",
      bundling: {
        minify: true, // minify code, defaults to false
        target: 'es2020', // target environment for the generated JavaScript code
        define: { // Replace strings during build time
          'process.env.API_KEY': JSON.stringify('xxx-xxxx-xxx'),
          'process.env.PRODUCTION': JSON.stringify(true),
          'process.env.NUMBER': JSON.stringify(123),
        },
        logLevel: lambda.LogLevel.WARNING, // defaults to LogLevel.WARNING
        charset: lambda.Charset.UTF8, // do not escape non-ASCII characters, defaults to Charset.ASCII
      },
    });
  }
}
```

*notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/src/index.ts*

```js
export const handler = () => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {},
    body: "This is a test"
  }
}
```

Now when I run `cdk synth`:

```
...
Successfully built 02d6914d6b53
Successfully tagged cdk-8fdc30cb2c9ed412046010e799d65c0ea32740bedc9d91b938c57d400ad7b53e:latest
Bundling asset NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack/notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/Code/Stage...
esbuild cannot run locally. Switching to Docker bundling.
Resources:
  notifyTodoScheduleFullDayServiceRoleC004AA77:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack/notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/ServiceRole/Resource
  notifyTodoScheduleFullDay200FABC6:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket:
          Fn::Sub: cdk-hnb659fds-assets-${AWS::AccountId}-${AWS::Region}
        S3Key: da842e2df006207da8989140b01b302408f071b2f74188cae1f4624fd056614f.zip
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - notifyTodoScheduleFullDayServiceRoleC004AA77
          - Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1"
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
    DependsOn:
      - notifyTodoScheduleFullDayServiceRoleC004AA77
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack/notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/Resource
      aws:asset:path: asset.da842e2df006207da8989140b01b302408f071b2f74188cae1f4624fd056614f
      aws:asset:is-bundled: true
      aws:asset:property: Code
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Analytics: v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/zWOzQ6CMAyAn4X7qCImnoXEowd8ADK2SspPl9BND4R3d4x4+tLmy9deoIRzpr+SGzvmE3Wwvrw2o4qrdp303FndsrM4CDwTHoGNJ8eK9Axr4yZU9Zt3bkrKVougF7jviDNUwYzoKy2ojhpE+9/YVPLixZ64Tx0UFxaTmrVjS4e2fwCDnD7FFYobFNkgRPkS2NOM0Bz8Aem4EiHMAAAA
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack/CDKMetadata/Default
    Condition: CDKMetadataAvailable
Conditions:
  CDKMetadataAvailable:
    Fn::Or:
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - af-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-east-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-northeast-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-northeast-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-southeast-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-southeast-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ca-central-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - cn-north-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - cn-northwest-1
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-central-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-north-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-west-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-west-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-west-3
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - me-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - sa-east-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-east-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-east-2
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-west-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-west-2
Parameters:
  BootstrapVersion:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version
    Description: Version of the CDK Bootstrap resources in this environment, automatically retrieved from SSM Parameter Store. [cdk:skip]
Rules:
  CheckBootstrapVersion:
    Assertions:
      - Assert:
          Fn::Not:
            - Fn::Contains:
                - - "1"
                  - "2"
                  - "3"
                  - "4"
                  - "5"
                - Ref: BootstrapVersion
        AssertDescription: CDK bootstrap stack version 6 required. Please run 'cdk bootstrap' with a recent version of the CDK CLI.
```

Now when I try to deploy with `cdk deploy --profile xxxx` I get:

```
...
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-central-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
This deployment will make potentially sensitive changes according to your current security approval level (--require-approval broadening).
Please confirm you intend to make the following modifications:

IAM Statement Changes
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│   │ Resource                                     │ Effect │ Action         │ Principal                    │ Condition │
├───┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ + │ ${notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/ServiceRole.Arn} │ Allow  │ sts:AssumeRole │ Service:lambda.amazonaws.com │           │
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
IAM Policy Changes
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   │ Resource                                 │ Managed Policy ARN                                                             │
├───┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ + │ ${notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/ServiceRole} │ arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole │
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(NOTE: There may be security-related changes not in this list. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1299)

Do you wish to deploy these changes (y/n)? y
NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack: deploying...
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-central-1', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
Could not read SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version: User: arn:aws:iam::359163713835:user/lambda-functions is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:359163713835:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action

 ❌  NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack failed: Error: NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack: This CDK deployment requires bootstrap stack version '6', found an older version. Please run 'cdk bootstrap'.
    at CloudFormationDeployments.validateBootstrapStackVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:323:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:298:7)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:202:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:194:24)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:267:9)
NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack: This CDK deployment requires bootstrap stack version '6', found an older version. Please run 'cdk bootstrap'.
```

What exactly is going on? Why am I not being able to deploy my stack?

## Update

`cdk bootstrap`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  138.2kB
Step 1/12 : ARG IMAGE=public.ecr.aws/sam/build-nodejs14.x
Step 2/12 : FROM $IMAGE
 ---> 3147f2b9c981
Step 3/12 : RUN npm install --global yarn@1.22.5
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf8f25f59972
Step 4/12 : RUN npm install --global pnpm
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4310f7c1d337
Step 5/12 : RUN npm install --global typescript
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8380434f397e
Step 6/12 : ARG ESBUILD_VERSION=0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1acd8da9c4f4
Step 7/12 : RUN npm install --global --unsafe-perm=true esbuild@$ESBUILD_VERSION
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9cc9743c5a2f
Step 8/12 : RUN mkdir /tmp/npm-cache &&     chmod -R 777 /tmp/npm-cache &&     npm config --global set cache /tmp/npm-cache
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5b9c8267e6a7
Step 9/12 : RUN mkdir /tmp/yarn-cache &&     chmod -R 777 /tmp/yarn-cache &&     yarn config set cache-folder /tmp/yarn-cache
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 71ea1be33795
Step 10/12 : RUN npm config --global set update-notifier false
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f7ea8d8d458a
Step 11/12 : RUN /sbin/useradd -u 1000 user && chmod 711 /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c663ca63d996
Step 12/12 : CMD [ "esbuild" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 02d6914d6b53
Successfully built 02d6914d6b53
Successfully tagged cdk-8fdc30cb2c9ed412046010e799d65c0ea32740bedc9d91b938c57d400ad7b53e:latest
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://835950464690/eu-central-1...
Trusted accounts for deployment: (none)
Trusted accounts for lookup: (none)
Using default execution policy of 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'. Pass '--cloudformation-execution-policies' to customize.
```

Running `aws ssm get-parameter --name /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version --profile xxxxx --region eu-west-2` gives me:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetParameter operation: User: arn:aws:iam::359163713835:user/lambda-functions is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-2:359163713835:parameter/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParameter action
```

## Update 2

After help from @gshpychka I have noticed that it was missing some permissions. I have setup the `AmazonSSMFullAccess` and `AWSLambda_FullAccess` in my users account. Now the error original to this question has gone away. Now the error I'm getting is:

```
$ cdk deploy --profile todozito-lambda-functions
Reading existing template for stack NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack.
Retrieved account ID 359163713835 from disk cache
Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-west-2'.
Assuming role failed: User: arn:aws:iam::359163713835:user/lambda-functions is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-west-2
Could not assume role in target account using current credentials User: arn:aws:iam::359163713835:user/lambda-functions is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-west-2 . Please make sure that this role exists in the account. If it doesn't exist, (re)-bootstrap the environment with the right '--trust', using the latest version of the CDK CLI.
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-west-2', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.
Call failed: describeStacks({"StackName":"NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack"}) => Stack with id NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack does not exist (code=ValidationError)
This deployment will make potentially sensitive changes according to your current security approval level (--require-approval broadening).
Please confirm you intend to make the following modifications:


IAM Statement Changes
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────┬────────────────┬──────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│   │ Resource                                     │ Effect │ Action         │ Principal                    │ Condition │
├───┼──────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ + │ ${notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/ServiceRole.Arn} │ Allow  │ sts:AssumeRole │ Service:lambda.amazonaws.com │           │
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
IAM Policy Changes
┌───┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   │ Resource                                 │ Managed Policy ARN                                                             │
├───┼──────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ + │ ${notifyTodoScheduleFullDay/ServiceRole} │ arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole │
└───┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(NOTE: There may be security-related changes not in this list. See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1299)

Do you wish to deploy these changes (y/n)? y
NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack: deploying...
current credentials could not be used to assume 'arn:aws:iam::359163713835:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-359163713835-eu-west-2', but are for the right account. Proceeding anyway.

 ❌  NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack failed: Error: NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.validateBootstrapStackVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:323:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:298:7)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/cloudformation-deployments.ts:202:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:194:24)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cdk/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:267:9)
NotifyTodoScheduleFullDayStack: SSM parameter /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version not found. Has the environment been bootstrapped? Please run 'cdk bootstrap' (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/bootstrapping.html)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear as to what to do: `This CDK deployment requires bootstrap stack version '6', found an older version. Please run 'cdk bootstrap'.`

Comment: When I run `cdk bootstrap` I get `AssertDescription: CDK bootstrap stack version 6 required. Please run 'cdk bootstrap' with a recent version of the CDK CLI.`. This throws me in a loop. That's why the question is posted in SO

Comment: That's not an error. Post the full output of `cdk bootstrap` in the question.

Comment: The assertion message may not be pointing to the root cause.  The log output smells like a permissions problem.  To rule out bootstrap issues, lookup cdk-bootstrap's verson direcly from the parameter store using the [aws cli](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameter.html):  `aws ssm get-parameter --name /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version --profile <profile> --region <region>`.  What value do you get in the output (e.g. "Value": "8")?

Comment: @fedonev the assertion message may not be an error at all, but part of the synthesized stack. Would need to see the output when running `bootstrap` to be sure.

Comment: Moreover, I don't think that assertion can fail when bootstrapping.

Comment: @gshpychka thank you for taking the time. I have updated the question with the output of `cdk bootstrap` command

Comment: @gshpychka from what it looks like it is indeed permission. Getting ahead of the curve here are the permissions I gave to my user on AWS: `AWSLambda_FullAccess`

Comment: So there were no errors in `cdk bootstrap` after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/17942

And https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html

The version assertion warning is not related to your bootstrap version being old, its asserting it is not old. Look at SSM parameters in us-east-1.
Run with --debug

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my case, I saw that message, however cdk.out is created and correct.  ```cdk deploy``` works just fine too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. my company is using Okta which puts multiple credentials in the aws configure file. instead of performing `aws configure`
I need to specify --profile default  i.e.
`cdk deploy --profile default`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

This is extremely stupid mistake. I currently have 2 users in my machine setup and I was using the wrong one to deploy.

After performing `aws configure` with the credentials of the correct account I was able to deploy